# How to have part of texture remain constant with color ramp?

Tags: texture-painting, color, shader-nodes, toon-shading

I'm trying to have my model have a 2D look to it like my reference image on the right. I applied a color ramp to the model, but it drowned out the original white that I had textured. I want the eyes, stomach, and inner ears to remain the same white and not be affected by the color ramp. How do I go about this?
[image]

Comment: Assign them a different material

Comment: As @maddes8cht says... the material you created assigns colors (simply spoken) according to the brightness and shadow of the surface and changes with the light. The reference just has specific colors for specific parts.

Comment: In Edi-mode, select the parts you like to have white, then in the `properties`panel, section `material`, assign a white material to these parts (assumed they are all part of the same mesh)